# Trying to use array.push(); with newlines but in plain text, not html <br> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

recently I have been trying to grab HTML form input data, add a prefix, then write that back into a `<div>` For example:

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Please enter Details</h1><hr>

GUID <a href="https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx">(Generator)</a>:<div id="guidInput" style="display:inline;">
    <!-- Changed to an onkeyup="" method. Works the same but with less code. -->
    <input onkeyup="gen()" id="guidText" style="height: 16px;"></input>
</div>

ID:<div id="idInput" style="display:inline;">
    <!-- Changed to an onkeyup="" method. Works the same but with less code. -->
    <input type="number" type="number" onkeyup="gen()" id="idText" style="height: 16px;"></input>
</div>


<div id="command" class="command"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var command = ""; /*Here for future developement*/
    command += "";  /*Here for future developement*/
    document.getElementById('command').innerHTML = command; 
});


function gen() {

    var id = $('#idText').val(); 
    var guid = $('#guidText').val(); 
    var command = "";  /*Here for future developement*/
    var tags = []; 

    tags.push("GUID "+guid);
    tags.push("ID "+id);

    command += tags.join("<br>"); 
    command += ""; /*Here for future developement*/
    document.getElementById('command').innerHTML = command;
}
```

This does what I want it to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGKaR.jpg But I want the user to download the output as a file. To do this I implemented [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), and added this code to my files:

**HTML (placed above the `<div id="command" class="command"></div>`):**

```
<button onclick="saver()">Save</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function saver() {

  var text = document.getElementById("command").innerHTML;
  var newText = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
  var filename = ("File")
  var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
  saveAs(blob, filename+".txt");
}
```

That grabs the content of the `<div>` containing the output, and triggers a download of `File.txt`. The contents of this file look like this (from imgur.com link above.):

```
GUID qwertyuiop<br>ID 12345
```

This is where I'm having my problem. I NEED the file to look like this:

```
GUID qwertyuiop
ID 12345
```

With a line break after every part. the `<br>` is for displaying it on the site, but I need some way to make sure it's on a separate line in the downloaded file, and having no HTML tags in the file.

Comment: You're looking for `\r\n`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Do I use that to join the GUID and ID fields, instead of `<br>`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newText = text.replace(`<br>`, `\n`).replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

or

```js
function gen(delimiter) {

    // ... //

    command += tags.join(delimiter); 
    return command;
}

function saver() {

  // ... //
  var newText = gen(`\n`);
  // ... //
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is violating SRP: Single Responsibility Principle.

You are trying to do two things at the same time.

Prefixing and formatting in HTML are two different concerns and they should be separated.

After that, the answer will become obvious.

Comment: Consider adding a practical answer (or at least links to helpful resources on how your advice can be put to use) to your (otherwise good) advice. In its current form, it is better suited as a comment, not an answer. See [answer] for details.

Comment: I agree with Andrei, your answer provides no information for my query.